# MPI_Finalize and assertions?

Tags: c, error-handling, mpi

The MPI spec dictates to call `MPI_Finalize` in each thread before exiting. How does that work with runtime errors like assertions?

If I `assert(cond)` and `cond` evaluates to false, I have no chance to call `MPI_Finalize` because the normal program flow is changed. Am I supposed to catch `SIGABRT`, `SIGSEGV` and god-knows-what-else myself or does the MPI library somehow handle this itself?

Comment: I assume, that assert simply kills the program. removing threads needs to be called by yourself via lamhalt. but this is just guessing. You need to use proper error handling instead of assert to call MPI_Finalze etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own version of assert that calls MPI_Finalize after asserting.

```
#define MY_ASSERT(cond) do { \
    if (!cond) { \
        printf ("Assert (%s) failed at %s:%d\n", #cond, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        MPI_finalize (); \
    } \
} while (0);
```

Note that in any case the other MPI processes in your job need to reach finalize too.

Comment: That's a workaround, I give you this, but it doesn't behave like assert because it doesn't kill everything; Okay, your solution could be changed to actually write to `stderr` and `exit(1)` after `MPI_Finalize()`, but as you said, it does not `SIGABRT` the other processes. There has to be a standard solution to this standard problem, right?